# How to put a horizontal line below a toggle switch

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I was making an application and I tried to put a line below the toggle switch , the line should be of 100 percent width that should cover entire page , but line is just coming beneath toggle switch. can someone help me out ?

code is :

HTML :

```
<div id="main_paragraph">
    <p><b><h3>Mode of notification</h3></p></b><p id="p1">Select mode of     notification</p>
</div>

<div>
    <div id="row11"><img id="msg" src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/60/256/basic-message-icon.png" alt="message_icon"><p id="p2"> 
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Email </p></div>
        <div id="row12"><div id="p3"><select name="flip-3" id="flip-3" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
            </select><div></div><br>


    </div>

 <div class="h_line"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#main_paragraph {
    margin-left:3%;

}

#p1 {
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:relative;
}
#msg
{   padding-top:15px;
    height:20px;
    width:25px;
    margin-left:5%;
     float:left;

}
#p2
{   text-shadow: none;

    display-block:inline;

}
#row11
{float:left;  
  margin-top:25px;
  width:70%;
  height:100px;
  ]   
}

#row12
{   float:right; 
    display-block:inline;

    height:100px;
    width:30%;
    margin-top:25px;
}
#p3
{
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.h_line 
{   width:100%;
    height:1px; 
    background: #000000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/at7n0sbh/

Answer (score 0):

```
.h_line 
{  
   width:100%;
   height:10px; 
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;   
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/at7n0sbh/1/)

There can be any number of solutions for this. Just set position and left:0. It ll solve your problem

**EDIT**
[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/at7n0sbh/4/)

Comment: Sorry but, that is going out of the main div scope, I want it to be within the the second DIV.

Comment: Take a look at demo2. @vaibhav given html is wrong then

Answer (score 0):

Clear the floats div then the `h_line` class

```
<div class="clr" style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="h_line"></div>
```

[Update link](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/at7n0sbh/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... but it may be easier and more semantically correct to use a simple `<hr>` but that depends on the the overall usage context, if more content of a different topic or theme is going to follow the `<hr>` will be a good fit. If you're just looking for a non-semantic line under an element, try using a bottom border:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid  #000;
```

Also it looks like your markup has some unclosed elements and your css could use some love...

`display-block:inline;` should probably be `display: inline-block;`